# App Engine Modules Project using maven and Java

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, gae-module, app-engine-modules

I want to create an App Engine Modules project using maven in Java basically for frontend and backend instance.

For that I don't have any idea of module project structure as well as archetype of the module app engine project.

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) and try to make a deployment, then tell us what didn't work for you when you try actual development.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) walk you through creating an App Engine module using Maven.  If you use the `appengine-skeleton-archetype` archetype, Maven will create the directory structure for you.

If you're using Java for all of your modules (hint: you don't have to), you will want to create a Maven module corresponding to each of your App Engine modules.

The App Engine modules [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) explains how to configure your modules.